# Code crashes because object's .rad property becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, function, object, canvas, crash

I am creating an ecosystem with my code consisting of plants, herbivores, and carnivores being represented through circles. For some reason, my code has been crashing after a certain amount of time ranging from 30 seconds to 8 minutes but no more than that.

After doing some digging I have found out that the crash is a result of my object's .rad property becoming undefined for some reason. It's probably a result of me improperly setting up my functions but I haven't been able to find a solution.

```js
var plantSpawn = 5;
var herbSpawn = 3;
var carnSpawn = 2;

var myPlants = new Array();
var myCarns = new Array();
var myHerbs = new Array();

  //////////////PLANTS//////////////////
 
function createPlants() {
 
 reproducePlants();
 setInterval(reproducePlants, 5000);
 
} 
 
function reproducePlants() {
 
 for(var p=0; p<plantSpawn; p++){
  
  
  var rr = Math.round(Math.random() * 150);
  var gg = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  var bb = Math.round(Math.random() * 150);
 
  var plant = new Object();
   plant.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
   plant.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
   plant.rad = 2 + Math.random()*2;
   plant.skin = 'rgba('+rr+','+gg+','+bb+', 1)';
  
  myPlants.push(plant);
  
 }
}
 
function drawPlants(){
 var plantAmt = myPlants.length;
 
 for(var j=0; j<plantAmt; j++) {
  
  if (myPlants[j].x + myPlants[j].rad >= canvas.width) {
   myPlants[j].x -= 10;
  }
  
  if (myPlants[j].y + myPlants[j].rad >= canvas.height) {
   myPlants[j].y -= 10;
  }
  
  context.beginPath();
   context.arc(myPlants[j].x, myPlants[j].y, myPlants[j].rad, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
  context.closePath();
  
  context.fillStyle = myPlants[j].skin;
  context.fill();
 }
}
 
function killPlants() {
 plantDeath();
 setInterval(plantDeath, 30000); //play with inc
}
 
function plantDeath() {
 myPlants.splice(0,5);
}

  //////////////HERBS//////////////////

function herbsLife(){
 reproduceHerbs();
 setInterval(reproduceHerbs, 10000);
 
 herbsDeath();
 setInterval(herbsDeath, 90000); //1.5 minutes
 setInterval(herbsStarve, 10000); //10 seconds
}
 
function reproduceHerbs() {
 
 for (var h=0; h<herbSpawn; h++){
  
  var gg = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
  var bb = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  
  var herbivore = new Object();
   herbivore.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
   herbivore.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
   herbivore.rad = 5 + Math.random()*3;
   herbivore.skin = 'rgba(0,'+gg+','+bb+', 1)';

   herbivore.speedH = -3 + Math.random()*1.2;
   herbivore.speedV = -3 + Math.random()*1.2;
   herbivore.dirH = 1;
   herbivore.dirV = 1;
  
  myHerbs.push(herbivore);
 }
 
} 
 
function drawHerbs() {
 var herbAmt = myHerbs.length;
 
 for(var j=0; j<herbAmt; j++) {
  var hX = myHerbs[j].x;
  var hY = myHerbs[j].y;
  
  //HERB MOVEMENT//
  
  myHerbs[j].x += myHerbs[j].dirH * myHerbs[j].speedH;
  
  if (myHerbs[j].x > canvas.width + myHerbs[j].rad || myHerbs[j].x < 0){

   myHerbs[j].dirH *= -1;

  }
  
  myHerbs[j].y += myHerbs[j].dirV * myHerbs[j].speedV; 
  
  
  if (myHerbs[j].y > canvas.height + myHerbs[j].rad || myHerbs[j].y < 0){

   myHerbs[j].dirV *= -1;

  }
 
  
  context.beginPath();
   context.arc(myHerbs[j].x, myHerbs[j].y, myHerbs[j].rad, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
  context.closePath();
  
  context.fillStyle = myHerbs[j].skin;
  context.fill();
 }
} 

 
function herbsDeath() {
 myHerbs.splice(0,3);
} 
 
function herbsEat() {
 for (var k=0; k<myPlants.length; k++){
  var pX = myPlants[k].x;
  var pY = myPlants[k].y;

 
 for (var h=0; h<myHerbs.length; h++){
  var hX = myHerbs[h].x;
  var hY = myHerbs[h].y;

 
  var eX = hX - pX;
  var eY = hY - pY;
  var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(eX,2) + Math.pow(eY,2));
 
   if (dist < myPlants[k].rad*2) { 
    myPlants.splice(k,1);
    myHerbs[h].rad += 1;
   } 
  } 
 }
}
 
function herbsStarve() {
 for (var s=0; s<myPlants.length; s++){
  myHerbs[s].rad -= 1;
  if (myHerbs[s].rad <= 2) {
   myHerbs.splice(s,1);
  }
 }
}


//////////////CARNS//////////////////

function carnsLife() {
 
 reproduceCarns();
 setInterval(reproduceCarns, 20000); //20 seconds
 
 carnsDeath();
 setInterval(carnsDeath, 60000); //50 seconds
 setInterval(carnsStarve, 7500); //10 seconds
} 
 
 
function reproduceCarns() {
 for (var c=0; c<carnSpawn; c++){
  
  var rr = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  var gg = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
  
  var carnivore = new Object();
   carnivore.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
   carnivore.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
   carnivore.rad = 7 + Math.random()*3;
   carnivore.skin = 'rgba('+rr+','+gg+',0, 1)';

    //bigger random = slower//
   carnivore.speedH = -3 + Math.random()*2; 
   carnivore.speedV = -3 + Math.random()*2;
   carnivore.dirH = 1;
   carnivore.dirV = 1;
  
  myCarns.push(carnivore);
 }
}

function drawCarns() {
 var carnAmt = myCarns.length;
 
 for(var j=0; j<carnAmt; j++) {
  
  //CARN MOVEMENT//
  
  myCarns[j].x += myCarns[j].dirH * myCarns[j].speedH;
  
  if (myCarns[j].x > canvas.width + myCarns[j].rad || myCarns[j].x < 0){

   myCarns[j].dirH *= -1;

  }
  
  myCarns[j].y += myCarns[j].dirV * myCarns[j].speedV; 
  
  
  if (myCarns[j].y > canvas.height + myCarns[j].rad || myCarns[j].y < 0){

   myCarns[j].dirV *= -1;

  }
  
  context.beginPath();
   context.arc(myCarns[j].x, myCarns[j].y, myCarns[j].rad, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
  context.closePath();
  
  context.fillStyle = myCarns[j].skin;
  context.fill();
 }
 
 } 
 
function carnsDeath() {
 myCarns.splice(0,2);
}
 
function carnsEat() {
 for (var k=0; k<myCarns.length; k++){
  var cX = myCarns[k].x;
  var cY = myCarns[k].y;

 
 for (var h=0; h<myHerbs.length; h++){
  var hX = myHerbs[h].x;
  var hY = myHerbs[h].y;

 
  var eX = cX - hX;
  var eY = cY - hY;
  var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(eX,2) + Math.pow(eY,2));
 
  if (dist < myCarns[k].rad*1.2 && myCarns[k].rad > myHerbs[h].rad) { 
   myHerbs.splice(h,1);
   myCarns[k].rad += 1;
  } 
  } 
 }
}
 
function carnsStarve() {
 for (var q=0; q<myPlants.length; q++){
  myCarns[q].rad = myCarns[q].rad - 1;
  if (myCarns[q].rad <= 5) {
   myCarns.splice(q,1);
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">



<title> Ecosystem </title>



<!-- import external .js scripts here -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="Creatures.js" ></script>

<!-- modify CSS properties here -->

<style type="text/css">

  body,td,th {
  font-family: Monaco, "Courier New", "monospace";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  }

  body {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  }

  #container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 95%;
  height: 800px;
  }

  #fmxCanvas {
  position: relative;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
  border: rgba(255,255,255,1) thin dashed;
  cursor: crosshair;
  display: inline-block;
  }

</style>

</head>



<body>

<div id="container">
<!-- START HTML CODE HERE -->


<canvas id="fmxCanvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>

<div id="display"></div>




<!-- FINISH HTML CODE HERE -->
</div>

<script>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// DECLARE requestAnimFrame

var rAF = window.requestAnimFrame ||
window.mozRequestAnimFrame ||
window.webkitRequestAnimFrame ||
window.msRequestAnimFrame;

var fps = 30;

window.requestAnimFrame = (

function(callback) {

return rAF ||

function(callback) {
window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / fps);
};

})();

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// DEFINE GLOBAL VARIABLES HERE

var canvas;
var context;
canvas = document.getElementById("fmxCanvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvas1;
var context1;
canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
context1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");

canvas1.width = canvas.width;
canvas1.height = canvas.height;

var display;
display = document.getElementById('display');

var counter;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// DEFINE YOUR GLOBAL VARIABLES HERE
   

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CALL THE EVENT LISTENERS

window.addEventListener("load", setup, false);


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ADD EVENT LISTENERS

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mousePos, false);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MOUSE COORDINATES

var stage, mouseX, mouseY;

function mousePos(event) {
stage = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
mouseX = event.clientX - stage.left;
mouseY = event.clientY - stage.top;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// INITIALIZE THE STARTING FUNCTION

function setup() {

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// DECLARE STARTING VALUES OF GLOBAL VARIABLES

counter = 0;
mouseX = canvas.width/2;
mouseY = canvas.height/2;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CALL SUBSEQUENT FUNCTIONS, as many as you need
 
createPlants();
killPlants();
 
herbsLife();

carnsLife();

clear(); // COVER TRANSPARENT CANVAS OR CLEAR CANVAS

draw(); // THIS IS WHERE EVERYTHING HAPPENS

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CLEAR THE CANVAS FOR ANIMATION
// USE THIS AREA TO MODIFY BKGD

function clear() {

context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
context1.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

// clear additional contexts here if you have more than canvas1

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// THIS IS WHERE EVERYTHING HAPPENS

function draw() {

counter += 0.1; // EASIER FOR SINE COSINE FUNCTIONS

//if (counter > Math.PI*200) { counter = 0; } // RESET COUNTER

clear(); // USE THIS TO REFRESH THE FRAME AND CLEAR CANVAS

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// >>>START HERE>>>START HERE>>>START HERE>>>START HERE>>>START HERE


drawPlants();
drawHerbs();
drawCarns();

herbsEat();
carnsEat();
 

// <<<END HERE<<<END HERE<<<END HERE<<<END HERE<<<END HERE<<<END HERE
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// HTML DISPLAY FIELD FOR TESTING PURPOSES

display.innerHTML = 
// mouseX + " || " + mouseY + 
 " || Minutes = " + Math.trunc(counter/180) + 
 " || Seconds = " + Math.round(counter/3) + 
 "<br><br>" + 
 "Plants = " + myPlants.length +
 "<br>" + 
 "Herbivores = " + myHerbs.length +
 "<br>" + 
 "Carnivores = " + myCarns.length;
 


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// LAST LINE CREATES THE ANIMATION

requestAnimFrame(draw); // CALLS draw() every nth of a second

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Typo:** in carnsStarve you are setting your loop based on length of myPlants, but then use this iterator on myCarns array. If myPlant.length is e.g 10 and myCarns.length is 3, when q is 3, then it will crash

Comment: Please limit posted code to ask MVE, as discussed in the Help pages: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. All the Best.